# Hiding icefaces autocomplete list when there are no matches

Tags: java, autocomplete, icefaces

Friends!

I use icefaces ice:selectInputText item to represent input box with autocomplete hints list. Backing bean is returning list of suitable hints (it selects hints from one big list on condition that they contains characters already entered by user into input box).

All works fine. The only problem is that when there are no matches at all, I am trying to return empty list (also I've tried to return null instead) - I hope that list of hints would be hidden. But the list remains in the state which was created last time when there were more than 0 hints returned.

If it is possible to get rid of this undesirable behavior, could you please tell me where I can find info on how to achieve this.

thanks in advance,
Rodion

Answer (score 0):

We came across this issue as well in our project. There is a bug in ICEfaces that causes the view not to update when the item list becomes empty. This was reported in ICEfaces fora: http://www.icefaces.org/JForum/posts/list/16406.page

The fix is to patch the icefaces-comps.jar package as proposed in the forum post above.